# Bibtex with slashes in cite keys breaks hyperref

Tags: bibtex, hyperref

I've followed the convention in my bibtex database of having `Author1/Author2/...:Year`.  Thus, a cite key might look like `Jones:2003` or like `Jones/Smith:2005`.

In the past few years, I've noticed that the slashes in the bibtex key breaks hyperref support.  That is, the pdf file looks fine if printed, but clicking on a citation of any multi-author paper (where the citekey contains a slash) does nothing.  Single-author papers (with no slash) work fine.  I've tried with two different bibtex style .bst files.

IIRC, a few years ago it would work ok if I ran the paper through ps2pdf, but would fail with pdflatex.  It now seems to fail with both.    *(UPDATE: it seems I remembered wrong.  It works with pdflatex, fails with dvips + ps2pdf.  I could've sworn I tried pdflatex, but perhaps I then opened the wrong file.)*  I'm currently running texlive 2021 on a Mac, but noticed the same problem when arXiving.  I work with LaTeX through LyX (but have inspected the LaTeX file, and don't see any obvious problems).

Is this a known problem?  I've searched a fair bit (here, in the hyperref docs, etc), and didn't find anything.

Per request in the comment, an example LaTeX file that fails is as follows.

```
%% LyX 2.3.6 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[oneside,english,lowtilde]{amsart}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[unicode=true,pdfusetitle,
 bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=false,bookmarksopen=false,
 breaklinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 1},backref=false,colorlinks=false]
 {hyperref}

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Textclass specific LaTeX commands.
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\numberwithin{figure}{section}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
Works. \cite{Chvatal:1974}

Doesn't work. \cite{Erdos/Ko/Rado:1961}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{Research/Master}

\end{document}
```

Associated bibtex snippet:

```
@article{Erdos/Ko/Rado:1961,
    author = {Erd{\H{o}}s, Paul and Ko, Chao and Rado, Richard},
    journal = {Quart. J. Math. Oxford Ser. (2)},
    pages = {313--320},
    title = {Intersection theorems for systems of finite sets},
    volume = {12},
    year = {1961}}

@incollection{Chvatal:1974,
    address = {Berlin},
    author = {Chv{\'a}tal, Va{\v{s}}ek},
    booktitle = {Hypergraph {S}eminar ({P}roc. {F}irst {W}orking {S}em., {O}hio {S}tate {U}niv., {C}olumbus, {O}hio, 1972; dedicated to {A}rnold {R}oss)},
    pages = {61--66. Lecture Notes in Math., Vol. 411},
    publisher = {Springer},
    title = {Intersecting families of edges in hypergraphs having the hereditary property},
    year = {1974}}
```

Comment: show a small but complete latex example.

Comment: works fine for me in adobe reader on windows.  Which pdf viewer do you use and did you try with other ones too?

Comment: I'm on macOS, and Skim is my usual reader.  I tried Adobe Reader as well, and it also failed.  And the arXiv LaTeX build seems to have the same problem: for example, the hyperlinks to reference [4] in https://arxiv.org/pdf/2007.03707.pdf fail for me.  (So it's not _just_ my installation of LaTeX, anyway.)

Comment: The arxiv file is faulty. There is a 0 bytes at the end of destination in the annotation. `(cite.Erdos/Ko/Rado:1961/000)`. It has been produced with dvips + ghostscript 9.22. On miktex which has ghostscript 9.22 I can reproduce the problem, but with pdflatex or with a current texlive with ghostscript 9.55 everything is fine.

Comment: I'm running a 2021 texlive.  I'm seeing ghostscript 9.53.3 and pdfTeX 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2021).  Is this something that is likely to start working next time I update texlive, then?

Comment: I don't know.  The problem with latex+dvips perhaps, but as I said I can't reproduce it with pdflatex and imho it is quite inprobable that something changed there.

Comment: It seems somewhat problematical that the arXiv breaks on what seems to me to be a fairly common and sensible convention.  But I think I was confused before -- I just tested it again with pdflatex, and it worked correctly.  I think I was remembering the situation exactly backwards -- works with pdflatex, fails with classic latex + dvips.  Sorry about that.  I will update the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131965/discussion-between-russ-woodroofe-and-ulrike-fischer).